# PHP: Why won't timezone_name_from_abbr works with a GMT offset of 8?

Tags: php

I'm trying to use [`timezone_name_from_abbr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-name-from-abbr.php) with an offset of GMT+0800, but it doesn't return the expected timezone:

```
echo "timezone =" . timezone_name_from_abbr('', 8 * 60 * 60, 0) . '<br/>';
```

According to the documentation this is supposed to work:

> If `abbr` doesn't exist then the time zone is searched solely by the `gmtOffset` and `isdst`.

What I am doing wrong? GMT+0800 is a valid timezone for `Asia/Singapore`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not a very fancy answer, but it's a bug ([Bug #44780 - some time zone offsets not recognized by timezone_name_from_abbr](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44780)) that has been around for quite a while.

Basically, this particular timezone (and [some others](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44780#1225996056)) only resolve to a name when you pass an abbreviation, regardless of what the documentation says.

Btw, the return value is `false` in the case whereby the function can't resolve the name.

Comment: Hi, Jack. I see that the bug was closed in around 2014. I am using `PHP 7.1.17`. `timezone_name_from_abbr()` won't give me timezone for a lot many places (for example: `(-330 * 60)`). Can you please comment something on this? Is there any other related bug which is still not fixed?

Comment: @xyz As recent as PHP 7.0.15 there are still some timezone offsets that `timezone_name_from_abbr()` is not working for as reported in this issue: [#73988 zone offset not recognized by timezone_name_from_abbr](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73988). They marked that issue "wont fix". It appears there is some ambiguity in determining timezone using offset alone while also accounting for the possibility of DST. For us, `timezone_name_from_abbr()` failed in PHP 5.6.4 on AFT +4:30 (16200 seconds). I can't find what timezone your example of -5:30 is supposed to resolve to. Was that a typo?